# Convert 'field of view' to 'orthsize'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a perspective camera and an orthographic camera for particles.
I control the Field of view of the Perspective camera during the game, and I have to apply it to the orthgraphicsize in the same proportions.

When Fied Of View is 60, Orthsize is 5,
When the Field Of View is 120, the Orthsize of 15 seems to be roughly correct, so I multiplied by 1.5 times but it failed.

```
float t = Mathf.Abs (_MainCamera.fieldOfView - Vl) * 0.3f;
    float orthmove = (_OrthgraphicCamera.orthographicSize * (float) Vl / (float) _MainCamera.fieldOfView * 1.5f);
    _MainCamera.DOFieldOfView (Vl, t);
    Debug.Log (orthmove);
    _OrthgraphicCamera.DOOrthoSize (orthmove, t);
```

Answer (score 1):

Figure it out.

Credit: https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-calculate-horizontal-field-of-view.16114/#post-2961964

```
private void AdjustCamera (float aspect) {
    float _1OverAspect = 1f / aspect;
    _MainCamera.fieldOfView = 2f * Mathf.Atan (Mathf.Tan (60 * Mathf.Deg2Rad * 0.5f) * _1OverAspect) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    Debug.Log (_MainCamera.fieldOfView);
    _OrthgraphicCamera.orthographicSize = 5 * _1OverAspect;
}
```